# ios/objective-c/core-data: How to link two entities by key

Tags: ios, objective-c, join, core-data

What is the proper way to link two entities by an attribute so that you get the right values in the linked attribute?

I'm trying to follow a tutorial that has persons and addresses. In a conventional database you would have a field for personid in addresses and join on `person.id==address.personid`.  In this tutorial, it says after you have created a person and an address that you can connect the two via the following:

```
// Add Address to Person
[newPerson setValue:[NSSet setWithObject:newAddress] forKey:@"addresses"];
```

The tutorial on Tutsplus says:
"Creating a Relationship
To link the newAddress to the newPerson, we invoke `setValue:forKey:`, passing in addresses as the key. The value that we pass in is a `NSSet` that contains newAddress. Take a look at the following code block for clarification.

```
// Add Address to Person
[newPerson setValue:[NSSet setWithObject:newAddress] forKey:@"addresses"];

// Save Managed Object Context
...
```

We call save: on the managed object context of the newPerson object to propagate the changes to the persistent store. Remember that calling save: on a managed object context saves the state of the managed object context. This means that newAddress is also written to the backing store as well as the relationships we just defined."

Can anyone explain this to me?

Here is [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-relationships-and-more-fetching--cms-21505) to tutorial.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you created "addresses" as a to-many relationship to the address entity on your person entity in the model editor?

Comment: Show the data model you have as a result of this tutorial (screen shot)

Comment: They don't change the data model visually in Xcode; they just use code.  See above.

Comment: I had the same question.  Core Data uses internal keys to link entities according to zisoft's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26799394/4515489

Comment: ... so I think all you need to do is follow that tutorial's example, or perhaps simply put `newAddress.person = newPerson;` assuming the inverse relation from the Address entity to the Person entity is named 'person'.